# Calculate (& determine if converges): $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac 1n(0.5)^n$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Calculate (& determine if converges): $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac 1n(0.5)^n$

The above is a specific equation for $x_0=0.5$, but from here i'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: It converges, for at least two reasons: (i) alternating series (ii) terms go down real fast.

Comment: Be careful - your series is not defined for $n=0$, so the index can't start there. To determine the value of the series, consider the power series $1-x/n+x^2/2-x^3/3+...$. Does it look familiar? Where does it converge? How is your series related to this power series?

Comment: You are right, series starts at 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{x^n}n$$
for $\vert x \vert < 1$.